# mysql transacation in nodejs project with "npm mysql"

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, node-mysql, node-mysql2

I'm trying to make a **transaction(in the node code with mysql npm package)** that will select from a table and see if there is a record it will update (UPDATE) otherwise to create a new record (INSERT).
I'm using **connection pooling build-in with 'npm mysql2'** and I get interrupts between the logic of the transaction and its caused me a deadlock from the DB.
is there something to do if i don't want to create a stored procedure that will make the transaction instead?

Comment: How are you doing a transaction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.